# Catch specific response from graphql with apollo

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

In my app I have many of queries and mutations like mentioned below:

```
query name1($token: String!){
  session(authToken: $token) {
    user {
      id
    }
  }
}

mutation name2($token: String!){
  session(authToken: $token) {
    getSomething()
  }
}
```

If there are some problems with session on server side I get from server a response - session: null and it is OK. Because of many queries and many mutation how can I catch this specific response ({session: null}) and fire some method (in my case logout and destroy token in localstorage). I need some general solution (maybe some afterware or sth like that) instead of catching that response in every query and mutation.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

1- Have your server throw an Error instead of null and catch that error in your client using `apollo-link-error` https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-error

2- Write a custom Apollo Client that looks for the specific value ({session: null}). For that, I recommend looking at the source code of any of the available Apollo Links or check out this tutorial https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/creating-a-data-component-with-apollo-link-f0719d8193ee